# Are text variables and associated automation possible in Figma?

Tags: automation, figma, data-extraction

I've been using Figma for everything design-related.

Is there an automated way for generating certificates that get names from an (MS Excel) database?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There seems to be a plugin called [Scribe](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/952689592792995578/Scribe) which has mail merge functionality. I haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin **Google Sheet Sync** [https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/735770583268406934/Google-Sheets-Sync] can extract data from Google Sheets and merge them into your Figma's design. You can check documentation and instructions here [https://docs.sheetssync.app/] and there is another Google Docs integrations from the same author.